# Difference between usage of: "Now on" vs "Now"

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, difference

I am writing a technical paper. I have a statement of the following form that I want to write:

"From now on, we will use Theorem 1 instead of Theorem 2."

Is the word: "on", redundant here. In other words, does the meaning change if I write the following statement:

"From now, we will use Theorem 1 instead of Theorem 2."

If not so, then in what situation using "now on" means differently than using "now".

Comment: Now is the present time. From now on is starting from the present time.

Comment: @KateBunting The meaning of both the statements mean the same then?

Comment: The second one does not sound natural. I would only go with the first

Comment: "Starting from now" is another way of putting it, but I agree with Peter that "from now on" is much more natural.